# How correct way load viewpage in SPA(Asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I like to carry my Views, but do not want to work with @ Helper or partialview, gender or anything, but I want my routes pass by my controler

I do not know what is the correct way

Use or not @ Helpers?

I can use jquery load to call my controllers to alternative a @renderbody?

Comment: I want a brand new car, Italian is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any helpers.. But you should care about something like https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/#! while working
with mvc if youre from a different world.